# How to hide x-axis range where no data point is presented for Bokeh chart line

Tags: python, bokeh

Recently I have one requirement to visual data trend for some collected dataset using Bokeh, I know this can be done by Bokeh `line` function.

However, I encountered an issue when x-axis is datetime data type, technically it should skip the area from x-axis where no data point is presented, for the data used in my sample code, the next datatime following `'10:30:00'` should be `'14:00:00'`, but from the screenshot attached we can see `'11:00:00'` is still reserved. The same following `'16:30:00'` should be `'19:00:00'` rather than `'17:00:00'`.

**I added a made-up image to illustrate my intension, please carefully check the red-segment, x-axis and its label.**

[image]

Is there any way to trim x-axis where no data point is presented? Screenshot and sample code is attached as follows. Thanks.

[image]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import CrosshairTool


def get_data():

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['08:00:00', 11], ['08:30:00', 15],
                                ['09:00:00', 13], ['09:30:00', 17],
                                ['10:00:00', 15], ['10:30:00', 19],
                                ['14:00:00', 17], ['14:30:00', 13],
                                ['15:00:00', 15], ['15:30:00', 11],
                                ['16:00:00', 13], ['16:30:00', 17],
                                ['19:00:00', 15], ['19:30:00', 19],
                                ['20:00:00', 17], ['20:30:00', 13],
                                ['21:00:00', 15], ['21:30:00', 11],
                                ['22:00:00', 13], ['22:30:00', 17]]),
                      columns=['time', 'number'])

    column_data_source = ColumnDataSource(data={
        'x': pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S'),
        'x0': pd.Series([x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')]),
        'y_number': df['number'],
    })

    return column_data_source


def plot_figure(cds):

    plot = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=600,
                  x_axis_type='datetime',
                  y_range=(10, 20))

    cross = CrosshairTool()
    cross.line_color = 'white'
    cross.line_alpha = 0.7
    plot.add_tools(cross)

    plot.title.text = 'Number of Cars Collected at Different Time'
    plot.background_fill_color = 'black'
    plot.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    plot.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'time'
    
    line = plot.line(x='x', y='y_number', source=cds, color='white', legend_label='number')
    plot.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[line], tooltips=[('time', '@x0'), ('number', '@y_number')], mode='vline'))
    
    plot.legend.location = 'bottom_left'
    # plot.legend.orientation = 'horizontal'
    plot.legend.label_text_color = 'white'
    plot.legend.background_fill_color = 'black'
    plot.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.1

    show(plot)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cds = get_data()
    plot_figure(cds)
```

Comment: If the index of your DataFrame is a `pandas.DateTimeIndex`, you only have to resample it (in your case '30T'). This will fill all missing timestamps with `np.nan`. Bokeh doesn't show `np.nan` and so you have the wanted gap.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment the trick is to resample your data. I use `mean()` to fill with `np.nan` if an indes is missing.

Don't be confussed by how I creat the DataFrame. Somehow this didn't work creating the DataFrame line your did.

```
data = [['08:00:00', 11], ['08:30:00', 15],
        ['09:00:00', 13], ['09:30:00', 17],
        ['10:00:00', 15], ['10:30:00', 19],
        ['14:00:00', 17], ['14:30:00', 13],
        ['15:00:00', 15], ['15:30:00', 11],
        ['16:00:00', 13], ['16:30:00', 17],
        ['19:00:00', 15], ['19:30:00', 19],
        ['20:00:00', 17], ['20:30:00', 13],
        ['21:00:00', 15], ['21:30:00', 11],
        ['22:00:00', 13], ['22:30:00', 17]]
time=[]
number=[]
for item in data:
    time.append(item[0])
    number.append(item[1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':time, 'number':number})
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df = df.set_index('x')
df = df.resample('30T').mean()
df['time'] = df.index.strftime('%H:%M')
df
```

**Output**
[image: result]

**Comment**

In your data you don't habe any information about the year. So this line

```
pd.to_datetime(df['x'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

falls back to the default value `1900-01-01`. If you zoom out of the figure this is maybe irritating and unwanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment, but seemed different from what I wanted, the answer posted by me showed the made-up image and final result I wanted (sorry as I was not able to insert images by commenting your answer)